# Pipenv - Pipfile.lock - Difference when updated automatically compared to updated using `lock` command?

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I read online that `Pipfile` is always updated automatically whenever a new package is installed/uninstalled/updated.

But I noticed that `Pipfile.lock` is also updated automatically. Then what difference does it make to `Pipfile.lock` when it is updated automatically compared to updated using `lock` command?

Answer (score 1):

`pipenv lock` doesn't install anything. It just updates `Pipfile.lock` from `Pipfile`. `pipenv install` does two things. It installs **and** updates `Pipfile.lock`.

You might want to create a `Pipfile.lock` for example for initializing an environment in a Docker container or for your cloud-based environment, without installing anything locally.

Answer (score 0):

You run `pipenv lock` to generate the pipfile.lock file initially,

It's important for projects that are moving from pip to pipenv. The command allows them to create a pipfile.lock with all the packages int heir project environment.

```
pipenv lock --keep-outdated
```

Keeps all the pinned packages in your requirements file to their pinned packages.